# im trying to install body-parser into my project using hyper terminal but i get an error:

Tags: node.js, npm, ejs, npm-install, body-parser

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bodyParser - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'bodyParser@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 This package name is not valid, because
npm ERR! 404  1. name can no longer contain capital letters
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\shashank\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-03-21T17_26_44_276Z-debug-0.log

i am trying to install body parser in my project but got this error

Comment: What command is failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a typo.

The package is called `body-parser` not `bodyParser`.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Install it via `npm install body-parser`